# KoGrid Row Selection Binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, binding, grid, kogrid

I am using the KoGrid plugin to have a knockout grid with selection checkboxes. I  have the following code so far.

```
    function columnDefsVM() {
    var self = this;
    this.myData = ko.observableArray(GlobalJson);
    this.mySelectedData = ko.observableArray(SelectedJson);

    this.gridOptions = {
        data: self.myData,
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'TestEventId', displayName: 'Name' }],
        selectedItems: self.mySelectedData,
        enablePaging: false,
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new columnDefsVM());
```

Im just wondering how to I access the `selectedItems` property so that I can pass the selected values to an ajax call?

Or can I not do this and have to manually push the selected Id to an array using the `afterSelectionChange` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `gridOptions` you're passing in a reference to your `mySelectedData` observable array to use as the `SelectedItems` so you should be able to use the original `mySelectedData` variable instead of `SelectedItems`; they are equivalent. `mySelectedData` will be updated when the grid selection changes.

```js
function columnDefsVM() {
    var self = this;
    this.myData = ko.observableArray([
     {TestEventId: 1, Name: 'Object 1'},
     {TestEventId: 2, Name: 'Object 2'},
     {TestEventId: 3, Name: 'Object 3'},
    ]);
    this.mySelectedData = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.gridOptions = {
        data: self.myData,
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'TestEventId', displayName: 'Name' }],
        selectedItems: self.mySelectedData,
        enablePaging: false,
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new columnDefsVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid@2.0.6/koGrid-2.0.6.debug.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid@2.0.6/KoGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label>mySelectedData: </label><span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(mySelectedData)"></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="height:200px;" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```